# How to create two dimensional array with 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

How to create multiple dimentional array with 2 arrays?

```
      @param=("param1","param2","param3");
      @value=("value1_1, value1_2, value1_3", "value2_1, value2_2, value2_3","value3_1, value3_2, value3_3");

      Output:
      @out=(["param1"]["value1_1", "value1_2", "value1_3"], ["param2"]["value2_1", "value2_2", "value2_3"], ["param3"]["value3_1", "value3_2", "value3_3"])
```

I've tried this way:

```
      $j=0;
      foreach $i(@param1){
                push @{$out[$i]}, split(", ", $value[$j]);
                $j++;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what data structure you want to create.
However, I assume you are trying to create a *hash* of arrays (a hash table is also known as  *dictionary* or *associative array*), not an array.
The difference in Perl is that an array always uses integers as keys, whereas a hash always uses strings.

The resulting data structure would then look like

```
%out = (
  'param1' => ['value1_1', 'value1_2', 'value1_3'],
  'param2' => ['value2_1', 'value2_2', 'value2_3'],
  'param3' => ['value3_1', 'value3_2', 'value3_3'],
);
```

We can create this data structure like so:

```
my %out;
for my $i (0 .. $#param) {
  $out{$param[$i]} = [split /,\s*/, $value[$i]];
}
```

Note that `$#foo` is the highest index in the `@foo` array. Therefore, `0 .. $#foo` would be the range of all indices in `@foo`. Also note that entries in hashes  are accessed with a curly brace subscript `$hash{$key}`, unlike arrays which use square brackets `$array[$index]`.

You can access multiple elements in a hash or array at the same time by using a *slice* – `@foo{'a', 'b', 'c'}` is equivalent to `($foo{a}, $foo{b}, $foo{c})`. We can also transform a list of elements by using the `map {BLOCK} LIST` function. Together, this allows for the following solution:

```
my %out;
@out{@param} = map { [split /,\s*/, $_] } @value;
```

Inside the map block, the `$_` variable is set to each item in the input list in turn.

To learn more about complex data structures, read (in this order):

- [`perldoc perreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [`perldoc perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)
- [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

You can also read the documentation for the [`map` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and for the [`foreach` loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops).